# how to navigate a simple web link by windows phone mango 7.1/7.0 WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm new in wp 7 development. So I might be doing something wrong. I tried to use  WebBrowser in my first XAML code:-

```
  <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,2" Name="wb" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" Height="456" Width="444" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

In the code binding by C# as in code:-

```
    private void onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));
    MessageBox.Show("Completed.");
    }
```

It doesn't work it only shows a white box on the place of webBrowser control. Also it doesn't throw any exception. It just silently execute the code. I checked quite a many example in internet. Unfortunately none of the worked for me. I guess I might be missing some initial steps. For instance I tried exactly as it mentioned here:-
 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/5860/  
I tried both 7.0 and 7.1. It is same result for me. could anybody show me how to make webBrowser work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with web browsing on the beta of the WP7 Mango tools. I'm able to reproduce your error exactly, and the emulator's native IE browser won't allow me to hit any web sites, either. Can you confirm that you're unable to hit Bing or Google from the native web browser?

Here's a [thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/83494.aspx) from another developer who is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: well, it was my network problem. I tried same code as well as emulator in different network. It works correctly.